# Keep items in div locked in place on mobile resize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site: http://tele-verse.com/site

Where I have a div with an image of a phone, a group photo and a quote.

I have the button "Tell me more" in a certain position relative to the image and I want to keep them in the same position when the screen size is resized to mobile.

Is there a way to lock the items in the div in place?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
           <h4>Phone Systems</h4>
           <h4>for All Sized Businesses</h4>
           <div class='adPhotoBtn'>
           <img src='http://tele-verse.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/phone.png' alt='phone' />
           <a href='http://tele-verse.com/site/contact/'><button type="button" class='adButton'>Tell Me More</button></a>
           </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
           <h4>Mitel MiCollab</h4>
           <h4>solutions to keep your</h4>
           <h4>business connected</h4>
           <div class='adPhotoBtn'>
           <img src='http://tele-verse.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Collabphoto-transparent.png' alt='collaborate' />
           <a href='http://tele-verse.com/site/contact/'><button type="button" class='adButton'>Get Connected</button></a>
           </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
           <img class='quote' src='http://tele-verse.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/open-quotes.png' alt='"' />
           <p>I want you to know that we are very pleased with the quality of service Dan and the rest of your company provides. We sincerely appreciate your responsiveness and the way you conduct business.</p>
           <img class='quote' src='http://tele-verse.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/close-quotes.png' alt='"' />
           <h6>MICHAEL GEIGER</h6>
           <h6>IT Manager - Precision Gear</h6>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me

Comment: @NooBskie I added a div around the content that seemed to work but is there another/better way?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand whats wrong, The tell me more buttons are working fine for me the only thing that's messed up is your quote images is that what your referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added div around items and set a max-width seemed to work fine.

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
     <div class='homeAds'>
           <h4>Phone Systems</h4>
           <h4>for All Sized Businesses</h4>
           <div class='adPhotoBtn'>
           <img src='http://tele-verse.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/phone.png' alt='phone' />
           <a href='http://tele-verse.com/site/contact/'><button type="button" class='adButton'>Tell Me More</button></a>
           </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
     <div class='homeAds'>
           <h4>Mitel MiCollab</h4>
           <h4>solutions to keep your</h4>
           <h4>business connected</h4>
           <div class='adPhotoBtn'>
           <img src='http://tele-verse.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Collabphoto-transparent.png' alt='collaborate' />
           <a href='http://tele-verse.com/site/contact/'><button type="button" class='adButton'>Get Connected</button></a>
           </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
     <div class='homeAds'>
           <img class='quote' src='http://tele-verse.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/open-quotes.png' alt='"' />
           <p>I want you to know that we are very pleased with the quality of service Dan and the rest of your company provides. We sincerely appreciate your responsiveness and the way you conduct business.</p>
           <img class='quote' src='http://tele-verse.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/close-quotes.png' alt='"' />
           <h6>MICHAEL GEIGER</h6>
           <h6>IT Manager - Precision Gear</h6>
     <div class='homeAds'>
      </div>
</div>
```